# Click element with specific name in Python

Tags: python, html

I need find element with specific name and click it. The problem is: I got 10 elements with different xpaths and I need to click just one with name "NA":

```
    name = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="easSettingUserContainer"]/div[1]/div/span').text
    name1 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="easSettingUserContainer"]/div[2]/div/span').text
    name2 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="easSettingUserContainer"]/div[3]/div/span').text
    name3 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="easSettingUserContainer"]/div[4]/div/span').text
    name4 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="easSettingUserContainer"]/div[5]/div/span').text
    name5 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="easSettingUserContainer"]/div[6]/div/span').text
    name6 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="easSettingUserContainer"]/div[7]/div/span').text
    name7 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="easSettingUserContainer"]/div[8]/div/span').text
    name8 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="easSettingUserContainer"]/div[9]/div/span').text
    name9 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="easSettingUserContainer"]/div[10]/div/span').text

    try:
        if name == "NA":
            for i in range(10):
                name.click()
                # action.click(el=name[i]).release().perform().wait(wait)
                # self.delUser()
                # btnBack.click()
                time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(1,11):
    name = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="easSettingUserContainer"]/div[%d]/div/span'%(i))
    if name.text == "NA":
        name.click()
        time.sleep(2)
```